# transfer to live agent

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I'm working on chatbot development in C# on MS Bot framework.

I need to connect to Live agent when intent is none for particular conversation.

Please let me know the steps to connect to Live agent when bot unable to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find sample code on how to potentially accomplish this: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples.

If you want out of the box functionality and want to stick with Microsoft technology I suggest you take a look at [Power Virtual Agents which has handover available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-hand-off).

PVA can make use of [Bot Framework Skills](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-hand-off).